# Product of Dirac $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^\mu$ generate a representation of some algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, lie-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I need your help with an issue about Dirac gamma matrices. Precisely, I need to know if $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu$ generates an irreducible representation of some algebra. This problem has come out in the following treatment. I was trying to find all internal symmetries for the Dirac fields of the lagrangian (c, d are numbers)

$\mathscr{L}_{[\psi_1,\psi_2,A_\mu]}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu,\nu}F^{\mu,\nu}+\bar\psi_1 {i\partial\mkern-5.5mu/\;\psi_1}+\bar\psi_2 {i\partial\mkern-5.5mu/\;\psi_2}+\bar\psi_1 {A\mkern-5.5mu/\;(c+d\gamma^5)\psi_1}+\bar\psi_2 {A\mkern-5.5mu/\;(c+d\gamma^5)\psi_2}$

which describes two massless Dirac fields $\psi_1,\psi_2$ coupled to the electromagnetic field $A$. For internal symmetries I mean transformations of the type

$\Psi'=\begin{bmatrix}
    \psi'_1 \\
    \psi'_2 
\end{bmatrix}= E\;\Psi=E\begin{bmatrix}
    \psi_1 \\
    \psi_2 
\end{bmatrix}$,

where E is a generic matrix, which leave the lagrangian invariant. I used the helicity projectors $\frac{\mathbb{1}\pm\gamma^5}{2}$ (massless case) to rewrite $\mathscr{L}_{[\Psi,A_\mu]}$ in terms of $\Psi^{\pm}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \psi^{\pm}_1 \\
    \psi^{\pm}_2 
\end{bmatrix}$, where $\psi_{1,2}^{\pm}=\frac{\mathbb{1}\pm\gamma^5}{2}\psi_{1,2}$, as

$\mathscr{L}_{[\Psi^+,\Psi^-,A_\mu]}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu,\nu}F^{\mu,\nu}+\sum_{k=+,-}\bar\Psi^{k} \begin{bmatrix}
    i\partial\mkern-5.5mu/ & 0\\
    0 & i\partial\mkern-5.5mu/
\end{bmatrix}\Psi^{k}+\sum_{k=+,-}(c+kd)\;\bar\Psi^{k} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    A\mkern-5.5mu/ & 0\\
    0 & A\mkern-5.5mu/
\end{bmatrix}\Psi^{k}$

and if I want it to be invariant under $\Psi'^{\pm}=E^{\pm}\;\Psi^{\pm}$ (which mixes left and right component separately), i.e. $\;\mathscr{L}_{[\Psi^+,\Psi^-,A_\mu]}=\mathscr{L}_{[\Psi'^+,\Psi'^-,A_\mu]}$, it needs to be valid that

\begin{equation}
{E^{\pm}}^\dagger\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma^0\gamma^\mu & 0\\
    0 & \gamma^0\gamma^\mu
\end{bmatrix}E^{\pm}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma^0\gamma^\mu & 0\\
    0 & \gamma^0\gamma^\mu
\end{bmatrix}.
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now, for $\mu=0$, this condition gives ${E^{\pm}}^\dagger E^{\pm}=\mathbb{1}$, which means $E^{\pm}$ needs to be unitary. So I translate the previous conditions in

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma^0\gamma^\mu & 0\\
    0 & \gamma^0\gamma^\mu
\end{bmatrix}E^{\pm}=E^{\pm}\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma^0\gamma^\mu & 0\\
    0 & \gamma^0\gamma^\mu
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

or, more compactly,

\begin{equation}
[E^{\pm},\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma^0\gamma^\mu & 0\\
    0 & \gamma^0\gamma^\mu
\end{bmatrix}]=0.
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}

In principle $E^\pm$ is an $8x8$ matrix and expressing it as $E^\pm=\begin{bmatrix}
    A^\pm & B^\pm\\
    C^\pm & D^\pm
\end{bmatrix}$ (where $A^\pm, B^\pm, C^\pm, D^\pm$ are $4x4$ matrices) I can rewrite \eqref{3} as

\begin{equation}
[A^{\pm},\gamma^0\gamma^\mu]=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}

and similarly for $B^\pm, C^\pm, D^\pm$. I know that the Lagrangian I'm treating has a $U(2)$ symmetry and this would be realized if $A^\pm ,B^\pm ,C^\pm ,D^\pm\propto{\mathbb{1}}$, so I wish to deduce this from \eqref{4}. Usually it's done through Schur's lemma, but I don't know if $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu$ generate an irreducible representation of some algebra, because I'm not really proficient in representations/group/algebra theory and I can't find any reference. Do someone know if $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu$ generate an irreducible representation of an algebra?

Comment: Two comments: a) Lorentz boost $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu$ is not a closed algebra, you have to include rotations to form the full Lorentz algebra. b) The $d\gamma^5$ term in $\bar\psi_1 {A\mkern-5.5mu/\;(c+d\gamma^5)\psi_1}$ is not allowed, it's identically zero.

Comment: Thanks, so I can't use Schur's lemma unless I also impose that $A^\pm$ commutes also with rotations. For b), I don't understand why $\bar\psi \gamma^\mu \gamma^5\psi$ would be identically zero, since the product $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu \gamma^5=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_k & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_k\end{bmatrix}$ in Dirac-Pauli representation.

Comment: You can check that $\bar\psi_1 {i\partial\mkern-5.5mu/\;\psi_1}+\bar\psi_1 {A\mkern-5.5mu/\;(c+d\gamma^5)\psi_1}$ is NOT $U(1)$ gauge invariant.

Comment: So it's not identically zero, it's prohibited by symmetries. Nevertheless, I don't care about gauge symmetries here and, even if that term wouldn't be present in the lagrangian, the condition 4 for internal symmetries would be the same.